# iOs equivalent for share feature of Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am developing a xamarin.forms apps(android, iOS, windows). My app has a share feature which allows user to share audio files to other app and receive audio files from other apps. I have done that in android using intent filers and stuff, but not sure what I need to do for iOS. I read about share extensions. Do I need to use that or any other way? Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**
How to go about share extension in iOS xamarin?

**EDIT**

Share logic in Android:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
sharingIntent.SetType("audio/*");
sharingIntent.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "Share");
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
{
    sharingIntent.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, Html.FromHtml(new StringBuilder()
        .Append("<p><b>URL</b> : ")
        .Append("<a href='" + url + "'>" + url + "</a></p>")
        .ToString()));
}
sharingIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(path)));
Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Receiving Shared file in MainActivity.cs:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] {  Intent.ActionSend }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "audio/*")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSendMultiple }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "audio/*")]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    async protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Intent intent=Intent;
        String action = Intent.Action;
        String type = Intent.Type;
        if (Intent.ActionSend.Equals(action) && type != null)
        {
            if (type.StartsWith("audio/"))
            {
                Bundle bundleExtra = Intent.Extras;
                if (bundleExtra != null)
                {
                    Android.Net.Uri sharedFileURI = (Android.Net.Uri)bundleExtra.Get(Intent.ExtraStream);
                    await Upload(sharedFileURI); //upload logic here
                }
            }
            else
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .SetPositiveButton("Ok", (sender, args) =>
                {
                    // User pressed yes
                })
                .SetMessage("Not an audio file!")
                .SetTitle("Alert")
                .Show();
            }
        }
        else if (Intent.ActionSendMultiple.Equals(action) && type != null)
        {
            if (type.StartsWith("audio/"))
            {
                Bundle bundleExtra = Intent.Extras;
                if (bundleExtra != null)
                {
                    System.Collections.IList imageUris = intent.GetParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.ExtraStream);

                    if (imageUris.Count <= 1)
                    {
                        foreach (var p in imageUris)
                        {
                            Android.Net.Uri sharedFileURI = (Android.Net.Uri)p;
                            await Upload(sharedFileURI); //upload logic here
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .SetPositiveButton("Ok", (sender, args) =>
                            {
                                // User pressed yes
                            })
                            .SetMessage("Not an audio file!")
                            .SetTitle("Alert")
                            .Show();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .SetPositiveButton("Ok", (sender, args) =>
                {
                    // User pressed yes
                })
                .SetMessage("You have choosen more than one file!")
                .SetTitle("Alert")
                .Show();
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I also managed to share a audio file from iOS but no luck receiving file from other apps.

iOS code to share audio file:

```
var subviews = window.Subviews;
var view = subviews.Last();
var frame = view.Frame;
frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, 0, 0);
var uidic = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(new NSUrl(path, false));
var rc = uidic.PresentOpenInMenu(frame, view, true);
```

This above code doesn't allow to share audio via mail and doesn't add subject and a body to message. Any help on that? And how to receive a file from other apps?

Comment: Can you post the xamarin.android code that you'd like to be translated in xamarin.ios?

Comment: @DanieleDavì Please take a look at the edits

Answer (score 1):

To share data between your app and arbitrary other apps, you'll need to use a `UIActivityViewController`. Read through [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html) and [this article from NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/) for a rundown.

Comment: I tried it with UIActivityViewController. But it does not attach a audio file.

Comment: Code I tried:

`NSString stringText = (NSString)"data test";
NSUrl URL = new NSUrl(path);
var activityItems = new NSObject[] { stringText, URL };
UIActivity[] applicationActivities = null;
UIActivityViewController activityViewController = new UIActivityViewController(activityItems, applicationActivities);
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(activityViewController, true, null);`

Comment: @Arti Try passing just the URL, not a string and a URL.

Comment: can you please help me adding a subject and a body to the attachment. I want to add a subject and a body text in HTML to the attachment for email

Comment: can u please help me with share extension in ios xamarin to share audio files?